# Can you make a proxy file system?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, network-interface, chmod

Is it possible on Linux to create a proxy file system? So the idea is to have all the file operations done on one file system, but to have all the contents saved on another file system.

The problem I have is that the shared super computer has very small Linux drives for your home folder, but much larger network drives. However, the network drives do not support `chmod` (they are Windows), they are 700 by default though. Since the home folder is so small I need to install stuff on the network drives, but some installers fail because they attempt to execute chmod (pip for example).

So, maybe there is a solution where you can have the file system with the correct permissions on my home folder, but the actual contents saved on the network drive so that I don't go over the size limitations of my home folder. I do not have sudo rights.

Comment: The commands to read/write the files are also operations so the file contents will be where the file operations are done. What you want is to have metadata on one filesystem (your home directory on the small drives) and the actual data on another filesystem (the network drives). That sounds like a difficult problem.

Comment: Probably POSIX Overlay Filesystem (https://sourceforge.net/projects/posixovl/) is a tool that can do what you want. But I can't say more, as I have never used it.

Comment: If your Linux supports fuse, then `bindfs` (which doesnt need sudo) has an option to mirror a directory but ignore `chmod` calls. Or look at `fakeroot` which pretends to be root and pretends to do `chmod` commands by using LD_PRELOAD= on binaries.

Comment: @raj That seems to do the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @meuh There is indeed options for `chmod` calls which seemed promising. However, I get `fusermount3: could not determine username` which seems to be caused by the fact that this is on a network drive, the root cause of my problems.